# cosine operator in for loop in renderScript

Tags: loops, for-loop, renderscript, trigonometry

I am new in renderScript. I am facing a problem in cosine operator. It is very slow to run the cosine operator in a for loop. The cosine operator need to use in many level of for loop. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Cosine isn't an operator, but a runtime function. It can be a particularly expensive function call if you are in a deeply nested loop. Can you post your code to make sure we understand what it is you are trying to do?